# Send data to controller via Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I have a html table in with razor and I want to send some data from the table to a controller via Javascript.
I tried several different solutions but the data never seems to reach my controller while alerts are being hit. The breakpoints in the controller are never being hit which indicates to me that the data can't reach the controller.

I want the value of `@item.PartId`  and the value of `checked` to be send to the controller.

```
<div class="Table">
    {
    <table id="table1" class="table table-striped TableData">            
        @{var id = 0;}
        @foreach (var item in Model.PieceViewItems)
        {
            id++;
            <tr id="@id">
                <td>@id</td>
                <td><label>@item.PartDescription</label> <br /> @item.PartId (@item.StatusCode)</td>
                <td>@item.Supplier</td>
                <td style="width: 100px !important">
                    @item.TijdOpO3 @if (item.TijdOpO3 == "1")
                    {<text>dag</text>}
                else
                { <text>dagen</text>}
                </td>
                <td>@item.KeurCode</td>
                <td>@item.PromiseDate</td>
                <td>@item.WidthAndPartType</td>
                <td>
                    @item.PieceLengthWithUnit <br /> @item.NrOfPieces @if (item.NrOfPieces == 1)
                    {<text>rol</text> }
                else
                { <text>rollen</text>}
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (item.NumberReceived == "0")
                    {<text>NIEUW</text> }
                else
                { @item.NumberReceived}
                </td>
                <td>@item.VoorraadQty m</td>
                <td style="width: 100px !important">
                    @item.SalesOrderQty m <br /> @item.NrOfSalesOrders @if (item.NrOfSalesOrders == 1)
                    {<text>order</text>}
                else
                {<text>orders</text>}
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px !important">
                    @item.StalenOrdersQty m <br /> @item.NrOfStalenOrders @if (item.NrOfStalenOrders == 1)
                    {<text>order</text>}
                else
                {<text>orders</text>}
                </td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="IsChecked" onclick="ClickHandle(this)" style="width:30px;height:30px;margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px"> </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function ClickHandle() {
        $("input[name='IsChecked']").change(function (element) {
            var table = document.getElementById("table1");
            for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var lastorder = row.cells[12].firstChild;
                var check = lastorder.checked;
                if (check) {

                    var x = document.getElementById("table1").getElementsByTagName("tr");
                    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                }
                else {
                    var x = document.getElementById("table1").getElementsByTagName("tr");
                    x[i].style.backgroundColor = null;
                }
                //post item.partid and value of check to controller here.
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostIsChecked(string partId, string isChecked)
    {
        Part part = new Part
        {
            id = partId,
            isChecked = isChecked
        };
        //Do stuff
        receipt.UpdateCheckedStatus(part);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put a hidden input into `<tr></tr>`,and set its value with `@item.PartId`.Then use ajax to post data to action.Here is a demo:

```
<div class="Table">
    {
    <table id="table1" class="table table-striped TableData">            
        @{var id = 0;}
        @foreach (var item in Model.PieceViewItems)
        {
            id++;
            <tr id="@id">
                <td>@id</td>
                <td><label>@item.PartDescription</label> <br /><input hidden  value=@item.PartId/> @item.PartId (@item.StatusCode)</td>
                <td>@item.Supplier</td>
                <td style="width: 100px !important">
                    @item.TijdOpO3 @if (item.TijdOpO3 == "1")
                    {<text>dag</text>}
                else
                { <text>dagen</text>}
                </td>
                <td>@item.KeurCode</td>
                <td>@item.PromiseDate</td>
                <td>@item.WidthAndPartType</td>
                <td>
                    @item.PieceLengthWithUnit <br /> @item.NrOfPieces @if (item.NrOfPieces == 1)
                    {<text>rol</text> }
                else
                { <text>rollen</text>}
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (item.NumberReceived == "0")
                    {<text>NIEUW</text> }
                else
                { @item.NumberReceived}
                </td>
                <td>@item.VoorraadQty m</td>
                <td style="width: 100px !important">
                    @item.SalesOrderQty m <br /> @item.NrOfSalesOrders @if (item.NrOfSalesOrders == 1)
                    {<text>order</text>}
                else
                {<text>orders</text>}
                </td>
                <td style="width: 100px !important">
                    @item.StalenOrdersQty m <br /> @item.NrOfStalenOrders @if (item.NrOfStalenOrders == 1)
                    {<text>order</text>}
                else
                {<text>orders</text>}
                </td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="IsChecked" onclick="ClickHandle(this)" style="width:30px;height:30px;margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px"> </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

js:

```
$("input[name='IsChecked']").change(function () {
            var checked = this.checked;
            var PartId = $(this).parent().parent().find("input")[0].value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "PostIsChecked",
                data: { "isChecked": checked, "partId": PartId},
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
           
        });
```